# Hammering against not so duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, dupehammer

For [the question *"PHP child class doesn't have parent methods(possible configuration issue?)"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23828630/367456) I tend to use the hammer towards this one: [*"Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/367456) as it looks like a useful addition, however it is not an exact duplicate.

The so far two times voted close reason

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

looks fitting to me as well.

Now I've got a decision problem so I thought I'd put it on the meta-level.

Is it considered wrong to use the hammer as a tool here? Like if you've got a hammer, every problem looks like a nail sort-of?

Comment: I'd say reason number two.

Comment: Having a canonical Y U PARSE ERROR? question to close against would make hammer invocation not so bad (can't remember if we have one) Alternatively, if the hammer has been gauged as a successful endeavour by now, perhaps we consider expanding it to Y U PARSE ERROR? questions as well.

Comment: @DanLugg That seems like a bit of a stretch to me personally. They already have a close reason, so closing them as duplicates of something they are not a duplicate of seems like abusing the rules.

Comment: @TimSeguine Hence my "alternatively". There (at times) can be floods of parse error questions in the PHP tag.

Comment: @DanLugg I think I misunderstood that on the first read. That does seem reasonable.

Comment: @TimSeguine You were right to question it though; it's sort of subjective.

Comment: I used the second because of this line in the answer posted by the OP "So in the end - it was just a single typo that caused me to bang my head around for at least 6 hours."

Comment: The answer will be RTFM.  When not reading the FM has such drastic consequences then it does ought to be posted as an answer.  The hammer question does not apply as a duplicate, it opens with the RTFM quote.  And it was not a typo so the selected close reason is inappropriate.  Surely this has been asked before, digging up the dup is hard work however.

Comment: I would almost suggest to delete the question, but my only concern is that it's a consequence that I've never seen before(and obviously not very likely to happen, but still) and googling it, didn't get me anywhere. So it might possibly help someone. And I tried a lot of things, including using `php -l`, update, etc. So in the end - is it correct for the question to be on-hold and should I suggest it to be deleted?

Comment: You may want to give a bit more details for us here (hard to judge without domain knowledge). I, for instance, would totally approve of anyone closing pretty much any and all Java `"Why am I getting a NullPointerException?"` questions as a duplicate of `"What is a NullPointerException?"`, but I don't think it's a good idea to close them as `"How do you compare Strings?"` just because that **also** happens to be a problem in the code (but it wasn't asked about) (but, on the other hand, getting rid of questions that will never be useful to anyone is probably good, regardless).

Comment: I see, my only problem is that(while maybe not awesome) I developed the code while working for a client and posting the full code(which is probably the only way to try and reproduce the issue in this case) could a) get me in trouble and b) is not good working ethics. I do understand the fact that without all of the code people can only guess what the reason could be, but I was so desperate that guesses were my only option at that point. PS: what does "the hammer" refer to?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it considered wrong to use the hammer as a tool here? Like if you've got a hammer, every problem looks like a nail sort-of?

Yes, it is wrong to use the hammer here. The hammer is for duplicate questions, that question - like you said is clearly not a duplicate of the other one.

I understand, and sympathize with your will to save the other 4 people the trouble of close voting it, and the face your'e doing a great good for the system. However, giving non diamond users the power to close questions on their own was considered, and was decided against, at least for now.

The PHP room has the [cv-ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-ring) to help deal with duplicate questions, you know that, but for those of you who don't - it's a bunch of people who post [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) followed by questions that need reviewing or possibly closing in the php room. It's an effective tool, and I think it's as close as you can get to a solution in that particular case.